# change the title of a button in the correct cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to change the title of a button in a dynamic cell if that button was clicked but am getting stuck:

I have:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(id)sender
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSIndexPath *indexPath =
    [self.tableView
     indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"row::%d",row);
    ResultsCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.favoriteButton setTitle:@"favorited" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

and it works down to my `NSLog(@"row::%d",row);` but Im not sure how to get the second part right? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the button's "state" is. Or even cell state. Just because there could be lot of buttons and different titles for them, and you can configure each button like this

```
[yourButton setTitle:@"Add to favourite" forState:UIControlStateDefault];
[yourButton setTitle:@"Favourite" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Then just set needed state:

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    sender.selected = !sender.selected; // Toggle "selected" state
}
```

Comment: I like where this is going but what is selected suppose to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
[btn setTitle:@"favorited" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

A reference to the button that was clicked is being sent to your method.  You just need to use it!

Comment: - (IBAction)buttonWasPressed:(UIButton *) sender { sender.title = @"favourite" }